# How to open xml tab panel to view request in soap ui

Tags: soapui

I am using soap ui to test REST API using in our project and there need to send multipart form data attach with an image. There need xml tab panel to do some setup in request. Could anyone please tell how to open xml tab panel for a request. Your help is highly appreciated. The xml tab panel view need to be set as in below given link.
https://www.soapui.org/docs/soap-and-wsdl/attachments/

Comment: Did you try the documentation? https://www.soapui.org/docs/soap-and-wsdl/reference/request-interface/

Comment: I try it. But there they mentioned that xml editor is always available it is not, and also there is no any hint how to open xml editor for request.

Answer (score 1):

You need to distinguish between **SOAP and REST API**.

Your API seems to be REST, but your link leads to SOAP TestStep documentation.
I made a screenshot of a REST request, see bellow.

[image]

Comment: Yes, It is in soap ui and I try to use test REST API.  There it is possible to attach images and what I need is to set Part attribute of attached images to use them as a parameter which is describe in above given link

Comment: @KarelHusa's point is that there are two API types.  One is REST and one is SOAP.  SoapUI can be used to call either, but you seem to be mixing up SOAP and REST.  Look at the Karel's guide above and the REST documentation on the SmartBear site.

Comment: @ChrisAdams Thank you for the clarification